# Searchkick neo4j: search not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, neo4j.rb

I have used  gem `searchkick` & gem `neo4j`

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :first_name
  property :last_name
  property :email

  searchkick callbacks: :async

  def search_data
    {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      email: email
    }
  end
end
```

> (User.search 'suresh', fields: [:first_name, :last_name]).count
>   => 22
>
> (User.search 'sures', fields: [:first_name, :last_name]).count
>   => 0

I want to have all result even if I type `Su` , please help me?

**Brian suggestion**

> (User.search('su', fields: [:first_name, :last_name], misspellings: {edit_distance: 2})).map(&:first_name)
>
> => ["Sam", "Marilet", "aa", "asd", "Maricel"]
>
> (User.search('sure', fields: [:first_name, :last_name], misspellings: {edit_distance: 3})).map(&:first_name)
>
> => ["Herlinda", "Brent", "Andy", "suresh"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at @brains suggestion and bit more research I was able to achieve it by following changes

Updated Model looks like :

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :first_name
  property :last_name
  property :email

  searchkick word_start: [:first_name, :last_name]


  def search_data
    {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name
    }
end
```

Updated query looks like :

```
  users = User.search('su', operator: "or",
                                    fields: [:first_name, :last_name],
                                    misspellings: {below: 5},
                                    match: :word_start,
                                    where: {id: mutual_stay_pal_ids},
                                    page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

After changes do not forget to re-index the data `User.reindex`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `edit_distance` option:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#misspellings

Example:

```
User.search('suresh', fields: [:first_name, :last_name], misspellings: {edit_distance: 2})
```

Comment: Thanks @brian I have pasted the output of answer gven by you, but it seems like some thing wrong?

Comment: You might try doing a `User.reindex` first

Comment: I have added the exact changes that I have done , thanks for your help